# Update table with data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck on this one. I have three tables:

```
Table 1:
**ORDERS**

    | ORDER_NO | PRODUCT_NO | CLIENT_NO | UNITS | ORDER_DATE |

Table 2:
**CLIENTS**

| CLIENT_NO | NAME | LOCATION | SELLER_NO | OWES | OVERPAID | CREDIT_LIMIT |

Table 3:
**PRODUCTS**

| PRODUCT_NO | DESCRIPTION | UNIT_PRICE | AVAILABLE_STOCK |
```

Now, what I have to do is to update column OWES in table CLIENTS so it contains total amount of money of all the orders they made.

This is as far as I got:

```
update CLIENTS set OWES = (select sum(o.UNITS) from ORDERS o where CLIENTS.CLIENT_NO = o.CLIENT_NO);
```

That seems to work just fine to get a total number of orders, but than I have to multiply it by the price of given item (whichever the order was for) and I get myself confused.

I tried for example:

```
update CLIENTS set OWES = ( select sum(o.UNITS) from ORDERS o  where CLIENTS.CLIENT_NO = o.CLIENT_NO)*(select UNIT_PRICE from PRODUCTS where PRODUCT_NO= any(select PRODUCT_NO from ORDERS));
```

But that returns *ERROR 1242 (21000): Subquery returns more than 1 row*

What am I doing wrong? Would it be better to use *update CLIENTS as ( some complicated sub query goes here)* ?
Can anyone help me out and be so kind to throw in some explanation why such solution and not some other? It just seem like I didn't get something on more basic level and now I'm struggling.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just do a `join` in the subquery and do the appropriate aggregation:

```
update CLIENTS
    set OWES = (select sum(o.UNITS * p.unit_price)
                from ORDERS o join
                     products p
                     on o.product_no = p.product_no
                where CLIENTS.CLIENT_NO = o.CLIENT_NO
               );
```

Comment: Thank you ever so much. I suspected that I am over-working this in my head. It works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. The general syntax for updating from other tables is:

```
UPDATE table1
JOIN table2 ON table2.mycolumn = table1.mycolumn
JOIN (
  SELECT foo, SUM(bar) as sumbar FROM table3) table3sum ON table3sum.foo = table1.foo
SET
table1.foo = table2.bar,
table1.baz = table3sum.sumbar
```